# Searching a database by more than one column (similar to Google)

Tags: jsp, servlets, search-engine

Is it possible to search a database by entering a single keyword using a single text box which is something similar to Google? I know Google have their own search pattern. I just want to know whether it is possible to search a database table similar to a Google search.

For example, there is a text box, where the input is given as a date, the output is displayed based on the given date. Similarly if I am entering a name in the same text box, the output should be displayed based on that name. I tried using the query below; it will search and display results that match file description column, which is based on single column search.

```
String query = "Select * from file1 where filedesc like '"+id+"%' and status='Y'";
```

I can use the below query in order to get the results by giving multiple keywords using more than one text box related to that column.

```
String query = Select * from file1 where filedesc where id='' or status='Y' or date='';
```

while searching Google i came across FULL TEXT SEARCH from mysql,where the accuracy of a full text search is some what moderate.any suggestions?

Comment: `filedesc like '"+id+"%'` concatenating user input is strongly discouraged because it causes SQL Injection vulnerability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a robust solution, you might want to look at [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) or [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)